# How to create slack dialog using Botman.io

Tags: php, laravel, bots, slack

How do I create a Dialog box in Slack using Botman? I achieved creating a dropdown menu and button using Botman in the Slack app. But after selecting a value from the dropdown, I need to trigger a Slack dialog box. How I can achieve it?

Comment: I just gone through the file structure of slack 
vendor/botman/driver-slack/src/Extensions I found dialog.php file but its not completed as its class or functions are not defined. It means botman team is working on this thing. we may need to wait for it.

Comment: I have not got any response till now. No one faced this situation yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the full implementation in [this commit](https://github.com/botman/driver-slack/commit/d409e86e3609e3526d53ea25b5f7b76b5577068f).

First, you have to extend the **BotMan\Drivers\Slack\Extensions\Dialog** class.
For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\BotMan\Dialogs;

use BotMan\Drivers\Slack\Extensions\Dialog;

class TestDialog extends Dialog
{
    /**
     * Build your form.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function buildForm()
    {
        $this->title = 'Test dialog';
        $this->callbackId = 'test-dialog-callback-id';

        $this->text('Text', 'text');
    }
}
```

Then, you can send the dialog in your [conversation](https://botman.io/2.0/conversations)'s run method:

```
<?php

namespace App\BotMan\Conversations;

use App\BotMan\Dialogs\TestDialog;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Incoming\Answer;

class TestConversation extends Conversation
{
    public function run()
    {
        $response = $this->sendDialog(new TestDialog, function (Answer $answer) {
            $value = $answer->getValue()['text'];

            // ...
        });
    }
}
```